# Standard method of making random selections within Rank Selection

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

I'm working on an Evolutionary Algorithms framework, but I've hit a bit of confusion when it comes to the random selection method used within Ranked Selection; should I be using the same method used in Roulette Wheel Selection (i.e. selecting each solution independently), or should I use the same method used in Stochastic Universal Sampling (i.e. selecting all solutions simultaneously). I know the latter would probably be better, but I don't want to implement it this way if it's not standard practice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since every time people address Rank Selection they talk about Roulette Wheel, and SUS works with probabilities itself, and with a reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13696985/1805756) it seems you should select like Roulette Wheel.